# useEffect calling function infinitely

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that fetches and dispays data. I need this function to be called twice, once when the page loads and when InfiniteScroll calls it. The problem is that when getData is called by useEffect it goes on forever.

Code:

```
const getData = async(page) => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    
    axios.get(`/api?page=${page}&limit=10`, { cancelToken: source.token })
    .then(res => {
        setProducts(prevProducts => {
            return [...new Set([...prevProducts, ...res.data])]
        })     
        setHasMore(res.data.length > 0)

        console.log(res.data)
    }).catch(e => {
        if (axios.isCancel(e)) return 
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, [getData])

const handlePagination = () => {
    setPage(page + 1)
}

 ...

   <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={products.length}
      next={handlePagination}
      hasMore={hasMore}
    >
     ... 
   </InfiniteScroll>
```

When getData gets called by useEffect it goes forever. Just to note I'm using react-infinite-scroll-component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your effect will be changed as:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, [page])
```

So that, when the page changes, I mean scrolling ends, new data will be fetched.

**You were facing infinite loops because you were getting data on getting data. Sounds weird but it happened.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your useEffect like this

```
useEffect(() => {
 getData(),
 return () => {}
}, [])
```

Comment: This will definitely break the infinite loop but it won't serve the purpose of infinite-scroll.

Comment: Replace [] to [page]

Comment: Right, that's what my answer is.

Comment: Yes you're right. I think is the best solution